# Devxpress ASPxScheduler access control using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, scheduler

I have a hyperlink in ASPxScheduler VerticalAppointmentTemplate. I want to access the same in runtime code behind.

My Aspx code is as below:

```
<dxwschs:ASPxScheduler ID="CalendarView" runat="server" Width="100%" ActiveViewType="Day">
    <ResourceNavigator EnableIncreaseDecrease="false" />
    <Views>
        <DayView ResourcesPerPage="1">
            <WorkTime Start="08:00:00" End="17:00:00" />
            <Templates>
                <VerticalAppointmentTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="CalendarViewLink" runat="server" Text="View"></asp:HyperLink>
                </VerticalAppointmentTemplate>
            </Templates>
        </DayView>
    </Views>
    <OptionsBehavior ShowViewSelector="false" />
    <Storage EnableReminders="false" />
</dxwschs:ASPxScheduler>
```

I have tried using various ways like

```
ASPxHyperLink calendarViewLink = (ASPxHyperLink)CalendarView.FindControl("CalendarViewLink");//Method 1
ASPxHyperLink calendarViewLink = (ASPxHyperLink)Page.FindControl("CalendarViewLink");//Method 2
ASPxHyperLink calendarViewLink = (ASPxHyperLink)updatepanelid1.FindControl("CalendarViewLink");//Method 3
```

also tried using rendered id of same link.

```
ASPxHyperLink calendarViewLink = (ASPxHyperLink)CalendarView.FindControl("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentControl_CalendarView_aptsBlock_AptTemplateContainer700_CalendarViewLink");
```

Please help me out for find the control. I have to bind the NavigateUrl at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to bind the link during the `DataBind` event of the `ASPxScheduler`?

I'm sure there must be a way to get a reference to your link using `FindControl` method however you will have traverse the whole hierarchy of controls (`ASPxScheduler->Views->DayView`) to get to the parent control containing your actual link (I guess it has to be the `DayView` reference against which you would call the `FindControl`).

However, there is another way to achieve what you need which I suggest you to investigate. Just define the `OnInit` handler for the actual link itself:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="CalendarViewLink" runat="server" OnInit="OnViewLinkInit" Text="View" />
```

then in codebehind you can set the `NavigateUrl` for your link using `s` parameter:

```
protected void OnViewLinkInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink link = (HyperLink)sender;
    link.NavigateUrl = "url";
}
```

The above OnInit handler will be called as many times as many links will be displayed.